# Apply function not looping through list in dataframe correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe that looks something like the below

| Client | Nodes |
| --- | --- |
| Client A | [32321,32312,2133432,43242,...] |
| Client B | [575945,545345,54353,5345,...] |

I'm trying to use the apply function to loop through each item in each list for a client and run the function on each number, so first use 32321 then 32312 for client A, then take the results of both of those and put them in a list and return that in the next column.

Right now my below function is taking the first item from each rows list and applying that, so each row gets the same result every time.

```
def FindNodeLL(route_nodes):
        for node in route_nodes:
            try:
                response_xml = requests.get(f'https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/{node}')
                response_xml_as_string = response_xml.content
                responseXml = ET.fromstring(response_xml_as_string)
                for child in responseXml.iter('node'):
                    RouteNodeLL.append((float(child.attrib['lat']), float(child.attrib['lon'])))
                return RouteNodeLL
            except:
                pass


df[f'Route Nodes LL'] = df.apply(lambda row: FindNodeLL(row['Route Nodes']), axis = 1)
```

Comment: please share your expected output.

Comment: It would be a list of tuples such as ((51.3232,-2.43432), (43.4324,-2.43243), (43.4343,-3.4343)...etc)

Comment: add it to your original question

Answer (score 0):

You just need to return after your `for` loop and instantiate your `list` within the function:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = {
    "client": ["client a", "client b"],
    "nodes": [[1, 2, 10], [11, 12, 13]],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


def FindNodeLL(route_nodes):
    RouteNodeLL = []
    for node in route_nodes:
        try:
            response_xml = requests.get(
                f"https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/{node}"
            )
            response_xml_as_string = response_xml.content
            responseXml = ET.fromstring(response_xml_as_string)
            for child in responseXml.iter("node"):
                RouteNodeLL.append(
                    (float(child.attrib["lat"]), float(child.attrib["lon"]))
                )
        except:
            pass
    return RouteNodeLL


df[f"Route Nodes LL"] = df["nodes"].apply(FindNodeLL)
```

Comment: Now it's just giving back a single tuple in a list ```[(52.5797512, -2.0439439)]``` , it just appears to take the first node and applies the function just to that.

Comment: Are you sure the other nodes are valid?  That was an issue for me when I used the data you provided.

Comment: My code returns [(42.7957187, 13.5690032), (59.7717926, 30.32611), (14.2769353, -11.0519163)] for the first example (3 valid nodes) and [] for the second as [11,12,13] are not valid nodes.